# JavaScript error on trying to add inner html upon button click

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I am learning JavaScript, and in this script I am trying to insert a simple text row on click of a button. I tried two methods and both are giving me an error.

```html
 <input type="button" value="getValue" id="getValue" />
 <div id="rowgen"></div>
```

```js
(function(){
    window.onload = function() {
    
    // Code to display a google map on page
    //...
    
    document.getElementById("getValue").onclick = function(){
        document.getElementById.innerHTML('rowgen') += '<p>Hello world</p>';
  };
   
    }
})();
```

I get the error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment

for the line

```
document.getElementById.innerHTML('rowgen') += '<p>Hello world</p>';
```

For the second method, I tried:

```html
<input type="button" value="getValues" id="getValues" onclick="genRow()"/>
<div id="rowgen"></div>
```

```js
(function(){
    window.onload = function() {
    
    // Code to display a google map on page
    //...
    
    function genRow(){
        document.getElementById.innerHTML('rowgen') += '<p>Hello world</p>';
    }
   
    }
})();
```

This time I get the error in HTML file:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: genRow is not defined

on the line

```
<input type="button" value="getValues" id="getValues" onclick="genRow()"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`genRow` needs to be outside your `onload` block. It doesn't exist yet when you're calling it.

Also, your `getElementById` call is fixed below:

```
function genRow(){
    document.getElementById('rowgen').innerHTML += '<p>Hello world</p>';
}

(function(){
    window.onload = function() {

    // Code to display a google map on page
    //...

    }
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you quite understand how `innerHTML` works; it's a property of your object:

```
document.getElementById('rowgen').innerHTML += '<p>Hello world</p>';
```

in your function should work.

I would avoid inline `onclick` attributes, but if you must use them, you have to expose your method to the global `window`, as so:

```
window.genRow = function() {
    // Code
};
```